# MS Access database able to be accessed in debug mode but not accessible when published

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, ms-access, iis, iis-express

I've written some basic code in ASP.NET that accesses a Microsoft Access database, which works when I run in debug mode on IIS Express, but when I published the application and tried to run on the actual website, I get the error.

> [IndexOutOfRangeException: There is no row at position 0.]
>
> System.Data.RBTree`1.GetNodeByIndex(Int32 userIndex) +2430497
>
> NIM_Tool.Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +2321
>
> System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +106
>
> System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +68
>
> System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3785

From modifying some of my code, I'm pretty confident that the database is unable to be found, but I can't figure out why it's able to be accessed in debug/release mode but not from the published mode. After clicking publish, all files went to the bin/Release/Publish/ folder from the root directory, which I then copied all the children of the Publish folder to the correct server path. The children files/folder also contained the correct MS Access database.

code from the DataLayer.cs file

```
public class DataLayer { 

static OleDbConnection conn;
static OleDbCommand cmd;
static String connString;
static OleDbDataAdapter adp;

private static void CreateCommand() 
{ 
    // have also tried hardcoding this to the production server path but this failed too 
    connString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("MyDatabase.mdb") + ";Persist Security Info=False;"
    conn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
    cmd = new OleDbCommand();
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    adp = new OleDbDataAdapter();
}

public static DataTable GetDefaultDeposit()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    CreateCommand();
    try {
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Table1";
        adp.SelectCommand = cmd;
        adp.Fill(dt);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
    }
    return dt;
}
}
```

And The Default.aspx.cs code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        DataTable dtDeposit = DataLayer.GetDefaultDeposit();
        string fixedCost = (string)dtDeposit.Rows[0]["FixedCost"];
    }
}
```

The MyDatabase.mdb file is located in the same directory as the DataLayer.cs file. I've tried hardcoding the database path as well to where it should be accessed on the server, but got the same error message as well.

Comment: Woo, yikes.  Don't put a database in your `/bin` folder.  Make a folder like `c:\inetpub\data\`. Try making that folder read/write for the account/identity for the application pool that your IIS is using (or just try "Everyone" for a quick test, to confirm).

Comment: oh whoops I miswrote my post... it's not in the /bin folder. it's on the same level as the rest of the files and DataLayer.cs file. Just edited my post to clarify this

Comment: I changed the server path to the /bin/Release/Publish/ folder (where VS publishes the website files), and originally I got the permission error that you were talking about. When I went to the folder settings and changed them to permit IIS all permissions, I received the error message I originally received (no row at position 0), suggesting that the file permission isn't the reason for lack of database access.

Comment: A little advice: you are being your own enemy when you catch an error and don't do anything with it. It is called "swallowing an error" and it hides root-causes.  Instead, I would recommend doing a re-throw, but use your (original) exception as the `.InnerException` and the outer exception description should contain your `ConnString`. (Just in case it didn't do what you thought it should)

Comment: One more thing: For security reasons, it is considered to be risky if 1) you have a DB in a path where it could be downloaded (ie, anywhere inside of the wwwroot). Please reconsider.. 2) you shouldn't have writeable files in a web server.  Think about it please.  Changing this might make it easier to manage permissions, paths, etc.

Comment: wow can't believe I missed that. you're totally right. I just removed the try catch clause and found that Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 provider is not registered on local machine. Thank you!

Comment: Do you mind if I post this as an answer?  (maybe get a few points for helping you solve it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little advice: you are being your own enemy when you catch an error and don't do anything with it. It is called "swallowing an error" and it hides root-causes.

Instead, I would recommend doing a re-throw. Put your (original) Exception as the `.InnerException`. You might want to have your `connString` in the .Description for the (outer) `Exception`. (Just in case MapPath didn't do what you thought it should, etc.)

Like this:

```
public static DataTable GetDefaultDeposit()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    CreateCommand();
    try {
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Table1";
        adp.SelectCommand = cmd;
        adp.Fill(dt);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new Exception("ConnString=" + connString, ex);
    }
    return dt;
}
```